# Collections of objects that generate triangulated categories and triangulated functors

Tags: category-theory, triangulated-categories

Let $F : \mathcal{D}_1 \rightarrow \mathcal{D}_2$ be a triangulated functor of triangulated categories $\mathcal{D}_1$ and $\mathcal{D}_2$, and let $\{ M_{\alpha}\}$ be a collection of object which generate $\mathcal{D}_1$, i.e. any full triangulated subcategory containing all objects $M_{\alpha}$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{D}_1$ (via the inclusion). I need to show that if $F$ induces isomorphisms 
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\text{Hom}(M_{\alpha}, M_{\beta}) \cong \text{Hom}(F(M_{\alpha}), F(M_{\beta}))
\end{equation}
then $F$ is fully faithful. The second part of the exercise is showing that if the collection $\{F(M_{\alpha})\}$ generates $\mathcal{D}_2$ then $F$ is an equivalence.

While this sounds perfectly easy intuitively, the problem is that I don't see how I should use the definition of the generating collection of objects to show that $(1)$ is true for all $X,Y \in \mathcal{D}_1$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Every object is a cone of a coproduct of suspensions of a generator. Induct on a decomposition in these terms.

Comment: @KevinCarlson thanks! If you don't mind, why is every object is a coproduct of suspensions of a generator?

Comment: You need numerable coproducts, so that  you also  have direct summands (as consequence of cones)

Comment: In that case, direct summands of direct sums of cones of objects in a set is a triangulated category. If the set generates, you have all

Comment: I think you could use [Stack Project, Tag 0ATH] to conclude. However, to use this, it seems you also need to assume the hom between degree shifts are bijective. I'm not sure if this is necessary.